# Transformers model from Hugging-Face throws error that specific classes couldn t be loaded

Tags: python, tensorflow, nlp, huggingface-transformers

Hi after running this code below, I get the following error.

*ValueError: Could not load model facebook/bart-large-mnli with any of the following classes: (<class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_tf_auto.TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification'>,).*

```
import tensorflow as tf
from transformers import pipeline

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli")
```

Could someone please help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 14):

I had the same issue! Somebody has commented here that you need to have PyTorch installed (https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/issues/16849).

To sum it up:

- Some models only exist as PyTorch models (e.g. `deepset/roberta-base-squad2`).
- Calling `pipeline()` selects the framework (TF or PyTorch) based on what is installed on your machine (or venv in my case)
- If both are installed, Torch will be selected
- If you don't have PyTorch installed, it threw above mentioned error
- **Installing PyTorch solved the issue for me!**
- In the GitHub issue, another workaround is mentioned:
  load the model in TF with `from_pt=True` and save as personal copy as a TF model with `save_pretrained` and `push_to_hub`

Comment: pytorch is already install, even then im getting this error

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the problem was caused by very slow internet speed. Its worth noting that if keeps failing while download is in progress, you can retry till it works (hopefully).

Comment: Surprised this hasn't been upvoted yet. Sometimes, the issue really is quite simple.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
!pip install pytorch-pretrained-bert
import pytorch_pretrained_bert as ppb
assert 'bert-large-cased' in ppb.modeling.PRETRAINED_MODEL_ARCHIVE_MAP
```

Now run your original code.