# Hugging Face - Could not load model facebook/bart-large-mnli

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I just wanted to test the `facebook/bart-largemnli` model but it doesn’t work and I don’t know how to fix it.

The code:

```
from transformers import pipeline
classifier = pipeline(“zero-shot-classification”, model=“facebook/bart-large-mnli”)
```

**The error message:**

```
ValueError : Could not load model facebook/bart-large-mnli with any of the following classes: (<class ‘transformers.models.auto.modeling_tf_auto.TFAutoModelForSequenceClassification’>,)
```

`classifier = pipeline(task="sentiment-analysis", model="roberta-large-mnli")` Works for example.

What can I do? I already cleaned the disk space.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Transformers model from Hugging-Face throws error that specific classes couldn t be loaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622895/transformers-model-from-hugging-face-throws-error-that-specific-classes-couldn-t)

Answer (score 4):

`facebook/bart-large-mnli` [doesn't offer](https://huggingface.co/facebook/bart-large-mnli/tree/main) a TensorFlow model at the moment. To load the PyTorch model into the pipeline, make sure you have PyTorch installed:

```
pip install torch
```

...and then re-run your code.

Comment: which version of torch is needed? i have torch==4.0.1 but it is also showing same error

Comment: You must be talking about some other package. torch's latest version is currently 1.13.1.

Comment: ah thankyou, i checked and found that entire github repo was not cloned on my desktop thats why i was facing this issue, my issue is resolved now

Answer (score 0):

On Hugging Face, not all the models are supported by TensorFlow. This model and (apparently) all other Zero Shot Pipeline models are supported only by PyTorch.

On the Hugging Face model selection page you can toggle options under Libraries to limit the model selection to the libraries you are using.