# Python works in Google Colab but not Visual Studio Code

Tags: python

I'm very knew to programming and I am trying to use the Hugging Face interference datasets. When I use the code to summarize text in Google Colab it works. However, when I use the same code in VSC, it gives me this error. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
!pip install transformers
from transformers import pipeline
summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")
```

```
following classes: {class_tuple}.")
ValueError: Could not load model facebook/bart-large-cnn with any of the following classes: (<class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_auto.AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM'>, <class 'transformers.models.bart.modeling_bart.BartForConditionalGeneration'>).
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70622895/transformers-model-from-hugging-face-throws-error-that-specific-classes-couldn-t) seems to be related to your issue.